# סימן יתק״ק and Shir Hashirim

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, torah-reading, leil-shabbat, shir-hashirim

In the copy of *Echa* I used this past 9 *Av*, the final *p'sukim* were followed by the notation "סימן יתק״ק". These stand for "ישעיה",‎ "תרי עשר",‎ "קהלת", and "קנות" (i.e. *Echa*). These are the four books of *Tanach* that have an unusual custom: when one reads their respective ends publicly, he repeats the second-to-last *pasuk* after the last is read. (We read the end of *Y'sha'ya* on *Shabas rosh chodesh* and the end of *T're Asar* on *Shabas Hagadol*.)

However, many *sidurim* in the *S'faradi* custom (for example, the currently popular "סידור עבודת השם השלם") include *Shir Hashirim* before *Kabalas Shabas*, and repeat the second-to-last *pasuk* after the last.

So I wonder: Do any communities/traditions have both the סימן יתק״ק and the custom to repeat the second-to-last *pasuk* of *Shir Hashirim*? (Knowing the provenance of each may help answer that.) If so, how do such communities reconcile the two?

Comment: [tag:acronyms]?

Comment: @DoubleAA, sure, but not over any of the ones already there, I don't think. Maybe over [tag:torah-reading]. Do as you see fit.

Comment: I was thinking over [tag:leil-shabbat] just like you don't have [tag:sukkot] [tag:rosh-chodesh-new-month] [tag:tisha-bav] or [tag:pesach].

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe. The question is about a _minhag_ of _kabalas Shabas_. But no biggie. As I said, do as you see fit.

Comment: In the teimoni shul I Daven in, when we say sheer hasheereem 3arab shabboth, we reapeat the last line I think and not the second to last.

Comment: @msh210, most Sefardic communities from North Africa (Algeria, Morocco and Tunisia) and Portuguese synagogues (in France at least) have the Minhag to let the kahal read out loud the last pasuk of any Haftora of year, then the reader reads the last pasuk, then the kahal says "Goalein Hashem Tsevakot Shemo Kedosh Israel" repeated by the reader.

Comment: @msh210, These communities have the Minhag to also read Shir Hashirim on Friday afternoon before Maariv. At the end of reading Shir Hashirim my Portguese shul has the Minhag to repeat הַיּוֹשֶׁ֣בֶת בַּגַּנִּ֗ים חֲבֵרִ֛ים מַקְשִׁיבִ֥ים לְקוֹלֵ֖ךְ הַשְׁמִיעִֽנִי and then הַנִּצָּנִים֙ נִרְא֣וּ בָאָ֔רֶץ עֵ֥ת הַזָּמִ֖יר הִגִּ֑יעַ וְק֥וֹל הַתּ֖וֹר נִשְׁמַ֥ע בְּאַרְצֵֽנוּ (Shir Hashirim 2:12) and finally Baruch Hashem Leolam Amen Veamen. However Jews from North Africa repeats only הַיּוֹשֶׁ֣בֶת בַּגַּנִּ֗ים חֲבֵרִ֛ים מַקְשִׁיבִ֥ים לְקוֹלֵ֖ךְ הַשְׁמִיעִֽנִי.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have trouble answering the question as posed because it asks about which communities "have the סימן יתק״ק." This mnemonic is included in some Bibles (both mss and printed editions) not because of communal tradition but because of the judgement of the scribes or editors. This being the case, let me rephrase the question somewhat: Is the common Sephardic custom of repeating the penultimate verse of Song of Songs based on the same considerations that motivate the repetition of the penultimate verses of YTQQ? According to [Joseph Ben Naim (1882-1960)](//he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D), it is (see *Nohg Bhkma: Oasr Blum Sl Mnhgim ʿl D. Hlqe HSuʿ Snhgu Bkl Qhilot Ysrel Bmzrh Ubmʿrb*, 247, also quoted in Spiegel linked below). This is also [James Kugel](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Kugel)'s position (see [*The Great Shift: Encountering God in Biblical Times*, 299-300](https://books.google.com/books?id=tbwzCwAAQBAJ&v=snippet&q=begone&f=false#v=onepage&q&f=false)). On the other hand, Prof. Y.S. Spiegel of Bar Ilan argues that this is actually based on the once-popular custom of introducing and concluding biblical readings with a thematically appropriate verse ([link](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=158877&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=16)). I might add that none of the older Sephardic siddurim I have checked mention anything about verse-repetition after Song of Songs. It seems that this custom only begins to be included in Sephardic Siddurim printed after WWII.

Comment: Hi Moshe! Welcome, and thanks for your insightful answer!

Comment: Thanks. I myself was troubled by this custom, when I first learned of it from Prof Kugel's book.